# How to output the queries from my sql database?

Tags: java, sql, sql-server

I'm getting this instead of the output

> Error java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver Error
>   java.lang.NullPointerException BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0
>   seconds)

```
import java.sql.*;

public class DBconn {

    private Connection con;
    public Statement st;
    public ResultSet rs;

    public DBconn(){
        try{
            Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");

            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://ARZ_Daunte-PC\\MSSQLSERVER;databaseName=OnlineAccommodationSystem","sa","root");
        st = con.createStatement();
        }catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("Error "+e);
            }
    }
    public void getData(){
    try{
        String query = "select * Addinglandlords";
        rs =st.executeQuery(query);
        System.out.println("record from database");

        while(rs.next()){
        String firstname=rs.getString("firstname");
        String lastname=rs.getString("lastname");
        String landlordID=rs.getString("landlordID");
        String email=rs.getString("email");
        String contactNO=rs.getString("contactNO");
        System.out.println("First name :"+firstname);
        System.out.println("Last name: "+lastname);
        System.out.println("Landlord ID: "+landlordID);
        System.out.println("Email: "+email);
        System.out.println("Contact No: "+contactNO);


        }

        }catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("Error "+e);
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: `ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver` suggests that location/jar holding package with this class is not in classpath. How are you trying to run this code?

Comment: @pshemo more info?

Comment: `String query = "select * Addinglandlords";` This line is wrong , it should be like `String query = "select * from Addinglandlords";`

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html

Comment: thnaks bro, its was a huge mistake that i didnt notice, btw still getting the same error. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need of jar that have the class com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver. This class is part of library JDBC to connect with SQLServer.

You can do download in this web site: https://www.microsoft.com/pt-BR/download/details.aspx?id=11774

If your project use maven, you can add this dependency:

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-jdbc/5.0.0.M5